# Is it ok to remove .ui class in semantic css?

Tags: css, css-selectors, naming-conventions

I'm migrating a project from bootstrap to [semantic UI.](https://semantic-ui.com/) Now what i don't understand that why i do have to put `ui` class to almost everything.

```
<div class="ui grid">
<div class="ui center aligned container"
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing from one of its source code [here](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/UI-Button/blob/master/button.css), you can see that each css class in the Semantic UI is identified with `ui`.... So if you delete the `ui` in your html's class attribute, the Semantic UI css won't work on your html element.

What I mean is, it's just the way the Semantic UI team design their css. Maybe their aim is to make their css not overriding the already existing css classes in one's project.

Comment: But people generally don;t use two css framework in same project. whats your opinoin? @samAlvin

Comment: @Paliza In my opinion having multiple .css files in the same project are common. For example, I tend to have `bootstrap.css` and `site.css` in the same project, where `site.css` contains my custom style.